# How to collect the same type of Map's value

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

We have one map which key and value both are int type. We have to search a particular value in the map and collect those key in one vector.
Code snapshot is like

```
map<int,int>m;
map<int,int>::iterator itr;
vector<int> v;
m.insert(make_pair<int,int>(1,2));
m.insert(make_pair<int,int>(2,2));
m.insert(make_pair<int,int>(3,2));
m.insert(make_pair<int,int>(4,4));
m.insert(make_pair<int,int>(5,5));
```

And current code is like:

```
for ( itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); ++itr )
{
    if ((*itr).second == 2 )
    v.push_back((*itr).first )
}
```

We like to optimize it. How we can do with STL algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you are going about this the wrong way, you probably want a multimap.

```
std::multimap<int,int> m;
std::vector<int> v;
m.insert(std::make_pair<int,int>(2,1));
m.insert(std::make_pair<int,int>(2,2));
m.insert(std::make_pair<int,int>(2,3));
m.insert(std::make_pair<int,int>(4,4));
m.insert(std::make_pair<int,int>(5,5));

typedef std::multimap<int,int>::iterator iterator;
std::pair<iterator, iterator> bounds = m.equal_range(2);
for(iterator it = bounds.first; it != bounds.second; ++it)
   v.push_back(it->second);
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like OP is trying to use key as value and value as key.

Comment: In one scenario need this, otherwise its a map where we are working on the key only itself.

Comment: Then take a look at boost::bimap.

Answer (score 0):

Can you swap the key with the value (=are all values distinct)? If so you then can use map.find() (which is O(log n)) to search for items. If not the code you wrote is the correct approach.

Another approach would be to create the vector at the time the map get filled with values, but this assumes that the filter criterion is known at insertion time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really do have a lot of them, there is `boost multi_index`, although with it just being pairs of ints it will probably be no more work to maintain two maps, the latter being a `multimap< int, int >`, or `map< int, set< int > >` which will work

Answer (score 0):

If at all the requirement could be changed, i.e. key - value could be swapped, one could go with a `map<int, vector<int> >` and build the map by pushing the data into the vector corresponding to the key. This way it could be optimized while building the map itself.

If requirement can not be changed as OP has said in one of the comments, then i think there is not much scope for optimization.